# openpyxl add query to excel join tables

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Is there a way of making a query like a "PowerQuery" but using solely OpenPyXl or any other Python library?

Consider I have data in different sheets that I'd like to be joined and filtered according to arbitrary criteria and I'd like this joined table to be consistent with changes in the source sheets (i.e. copying data to make a manual merge is not a good idea).

A simple stupid example would be like:

```
[Sheet1]
A    B    C
abc  123  Don't
abc  124  care
abc  125  column

[Sheet2]
A    B
bcd  234
bcd  235
no   see
bcd  236
```

Result in `Sheet3` taking only columns `A` and `B` and rows with numbers from `B` (can be an auto-filter):

```
[Sheet3]
A    B
abc  123
abc  124
abc  125
bcd  234
bcd  235
bcd  236
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution in pandas**

```
import pandas as pd

sheet_1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['abc', 'abc', 'abc'],
'B': [123, 124, 125],
'C': ["Don't", 'care', 'column']})

del sheet_1['C']

sheet_2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['bcd', 'bcd', 'no', 'bcd'],
'B': [234, 235, 'see', 236]})

sheet_3 = pd.concat([sheet_1, sheet_2])
sheet_3 = sheet_3[sheet_3.B.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, int))]
```

Comment: But isn't this copying data from source tables to a destination one?

Comment: Hmm, as i understood, you have two inputs `sheet_1` and `sheet_2` and one output `sheet_3`. You didn't mention that you want to modify one of yours inputs. You want to return modified `sheet_1` after process? You got two inputs anyway.

Comment: Yes @K.Maj , I need to be able to update source tables (I wrote "...I'd like this joined table to be consistent with changes in the source sheets"). Sorry if I was not clear and thanks for helping.